# To function or not to function, that is the question at hand

Tags: sql-function, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am working on some SQL statements for an ASP.NET application. One of the things that is required is to only display information in an open period. The period is updated automatically by the vendor software as the previous period is closed. So I finding myself doing a bunch of sub selects like:

```
where date >= (SELECT DATE(CONCAT('20', CONCAT(YY, CONCAT('-', CONCAT( MM, (CONCAT('-', DD))))))) FROM LIB/FILE')
```

Yes, each portion of the date is in separate fields.

Would making this query a function make the query more efficient? I have never created a function before how would I do that? My thought is having something like:

```
IsInRange(date)
```

So I can do `WHERE IsInRange(date)`.

Or is there a better way?

Comment: Is the sql MSSQL or DB2? Because of the ibm-i tag...

Comment: It is DB2/400... or whatever IBM calls it these days.

Comment: You would to call it like where date >= RangeDate(YY,MM,DD)

Comment: Ok, I'm not the DB2 sql guy...sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I created a view to join the fields into a single date, this at least cleaned up the query a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION toDate(yy CHAR(2), mm CHAR(2), dd CHAR(2))
RETURNS DATE
RETURN DATE('20' || '-' || yy || '-' || mm || '-' || dd)
```

---

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date <= toDate(yy, mm, dd)
```

Comment: Actually that would be `where date >= (SELECT toDate(yy, mm, dd) FROM LIB/FILE)` I wanted to eliminate the other select with a function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the point of the function would be for code reuse. If you are doing this in other places, or anticipate that then go for it.

Comment: I would be using it in many queries throughout this application. And how would I go about creating it?